# How to make Oracle UCP always store several available connections

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ucp

I'm creating connection manager class that would return `java.sql.Connection` to the customers of the class.
My goal is to always have 2 available connections in pool so I wouldn't loose time for creating connections. When I return the available connection, I need to make Oracle UCP create new available connection, so it would be always 2 connections available.

The problem is Oracle UCP doesn't have an option to control it. I've read the [UCP documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/preface.htm), but hadn't found any solution.

There is `setMinPoolSize()` method, but it controls **available + borrowed** connections, not only the available ones.

Also there is a harvestable connection functionality, but it harvests **existing** (borrowed) connections instead of creating new.

Note:
I'm using Oracle 11.2.0.3 and the latest `ucp.jar` (for Oracle 11.2.0.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such solution. When a connection is requested from a connection pool, it is either checked out from the pool, or a new connection is created. The cost of this is incurred on the Thread that does the request. If you would always want to maintain 2 more connections in the pool than in use, you are simply moving the problem: when a connection is checked out and `available < 2` then a Connection will be added. The cost incurred once again on the Thread requesting the connection (yes in theory this could be offloaded to a separate thread/executor, but that would complicate the pool).

A connection pool is intended to reduce the cost of creating connections, by keeping the connection available for re-use and thus 'spreading the cost', it is not intended to do away with the cost entirely.

Comment: Mark, thank you for the answer. Actually, I thought that creation of the available connection could be moved to a separated thread (I thought it is the way how it's done in UCP).

Comment: Libraries etc usually shouldn't create additional Threads (especially not in an application server), as it makes resource management harder (and if you use a lot of different database libraries it could also mean an explosion of Threads created). For example the initial poolsize might either be filled when the datasource is initialized, or the cost is incurred on the first Thread or Threads to request a connection.